# Fixed point iterations for real functions - depending on $f'(x)$?

Tags: numerical-methods, recurrence-relations, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-point-iteration

Let $f$ be a differentiable real function. In many situations a solution of $f(x)=x$ can be found as limit of the recurrent sequence determined by some initial value and the recurrence $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$.

To list only a few examples:

- For $f(x)=\frac{x+\frac ax}x$ where $a>0$ we get Babylonian methods for calculating square roots, see [Proof of Convergence: Babylonian Method $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n + \frac{a}{x_n})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82682/proof-of-convergence-babylonian-method-x-n1-frac12x-n-fracax-n)
- Using $f(x)=1+\frac1x$ we get [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) as the limit. This corresponds to the continued fraction expansion of golden ratio and the convergence of the convergents.
- For $f(x)=\sqrt x$ the recurrent sequence converges to $1$.

Of course, it can happen that the iterations do not converge. Examples of such functions are $1/x$ and $x^2$.

[Fixed point iterations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration) can be illustrated nicely with [cobweb plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot). The plots corresponding to functions I mentioned above are shown below. More similar illustration can be found [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14150/conversation/pictures-illustrating-iterations-for-x-n1fx-n) or [elsewhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=cobweb+plot&tbm=isch).

From the pictures it seems that the local behavior of $f'(x)$ might be enough to describe the behavior of the iterated sequence. (Whether it converges or not, whether the convergence is monotone, etc.) At least in the case that $|f'(x)|\ne1$ in some interval around the solution.

- What can be said about the sequence given by $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ if we have information about the values of $f'(x)$ close to the fixed point of $f$?
- Are there some references with proofs, related results, and so on.?

---

Illustration of Babylonian method for $f(x)=\frac12(x+\frac2x)$.

[image: Iterations of f(x)=(x+2/x)/2]

Illustration for iterations of $f(x)=1+\frac1x$

[image: Iterations of f(x)=1+1/x]

Iterations of $f(x)=\sqrt x$

[image: Iteratrions of sqrt(x)]

Iterations of $f(x)=\frac1x$

[image: Iterations of f(x)=1/x]

Iterations of $f(x)=x^2$

[image: Iterations of f(x)=x^2]

Comment: The topic you are interested in is called "complex dynamics" and there are many related results. I could give you the link to a lecture script dealing with such questions but since it's in german I don't know if you can use it effectively.

Comment: @Yaddle [The point of this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21893/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-site) is to serve not only to the OP but to other users as well. So the link might be useful at least for those users who speak German. (And I do speak German a bit.)

Comment: I will provide some links in an answer then :)

Comment: For $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ it can be approximated by $\frac{dx}{dn} = f(x) - x$ see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865370/good-closed-form-approximation-for-iterates-of-x21-x2x/1872168#1872168

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links to the scripts of two lectures dealing with complex dynamics written by Walter Bergweiler:

http://analysis.math.uni-kiel.de/vorlesungen/kompdyn1.12/Dynamik1.pdf (german/basics)

http://analysis.math.uni-kiel.de/vorlesungen/compdyn2.16/ComplexDynamics2.pdf (english/advanced)

I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

See the article on recurrence relations / difference equations here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Stability_of_nonlinear_first-order_recurrences

You will find the results/proofs you are interested in in any introductory textbook on difference equations.