# Confusion about a solution to a sequence problem about $x_n = \frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1}+\frac{a}{x_{n-1}})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I'm stuck trying to understand part (ii) of the following question;

Fix a positive real number a > 0 and generate a sequence by setting $x_0 = 1$ and, $$x_n = \dfrac{1}{2}\bigg(x_{n-1}+\frac{a}{x_{n-1}}\bigg),$$ for $n = 1, 2, 3....$

(i) The *arithmetic mean - geometric mean inequality* says that $(\dfrac{x+y}{2}) \geq \sqrt{xy}$ for all $x, y \geq 0.$
Use this to show $x_n-x_{n+1}\geq0$ for all $n= 1, 2, 3,....$

Answer is just := $x_n=\dfrac{1}{2}(x_{n-1}+\dfrac{a}{x_{n-1}}) \geq \sqrt{x_{n-1}(\frac{a}{x_{n-1}})}=\sqrt{a}$

(ii) Use part (i) to show that $x_n - x_{n+1} \geq0$ for $n= 1, 2, 3...$

Solution = $x_n-x_{n+1} = x_n-\dfrac{1}{2}(x_n+\frac{a}{x_n})=\dfrac{(x_n)^2-a}{2x_n} \geq0.$

The solution tells me that $x_n -\dfrac{(x_n)^2-a}{2x_n} \geq0,$ but I don't understand why this has to be a positive number.

Thanks.

Comment: Because $x_n>\sqrt{a}>0 \Rightarrow x_n^2>a$.

Comment: In part (i) you should have “Use this to show $x_n\ge\sqrt{a}$”.

Comment: I will mention that you can find other posts about this sequence, see [Proof of Convergence: Babylonian Method $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n + \frac{a}{x_n})$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/82682) and other questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/82682). A [cobweb plot](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884302/fixed-point-iterations-for-real-functions-depending-on-fx) might help you visualize the behavior of these iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In (i) you show that $x_n\ge\sqrt{a}$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so you know that $x_n^2\ge a$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ and hence that $x_n^2-a\ge 0$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. That immediately implies that

$$\frac{x_n^2-a}{2x_n}\ge 0$$

for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, since you know that each $x_n$ is positive.

Comment: Hi, I understand the 2nd term is positive from your explanation, but how do I know that $x_n \geq \frac{(x_n)^2-a}{2x_n}$? Apologies if that information is in your answer, I just can't see it. I'm still new to this analysis stuff.

Comment: @Ryan: You don’t need to know that: what you need to know is that $x_n-x_{n+1}\ge 0$, and that’s true because $x_n-x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n^2-a}{2x_n}\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

From
$x_n 
= \frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1}+\frac{a}{x_{n-1}})
$,
we get
$x_n^2 
= \frac{1}{4}(x_{n-1}^2+2a+\frac{a^2}{x_{n-1}^2})
$,
so that
$x_n^2 -a
= \frac{1}{4}(x_{n-1}^2-2a+\frac{a^2}{x_{n-1}^2})
= \frac{1}{4}(x_{n-1}-\frac{a}{x_{n-1}})^2
= \frac{(x_{n-1}^2-a)^2}{4x_{n-1}^2}
$.

In particular,
this shows that
$x_n^2 > a$
and,
if $y_n = x_n^2 -a$,
then
$y_n
=\dfrac{y_{n-1}^2}{4(y_{n-1}+a)}
$.

This shows that
$y_n
\le \frac14\min( y_{n-1}, y_{n-1}^2/a)
$
which should help.

Note:
None of this is original.